# Read xlsx upload via Django

Tags: python, django

I'm uploading files (xlsx) via my website and I think the files are being correctly uploaded.

```
def upload_file(request):
    print('here',request,request.method,request.FILES)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        file_json= convert_xlsx_to_json(request.FILES['file_query'])
        return render(request, 'drax_internal_dbs/drax_success_reactions.html', {'xlsx_file':file_json})
    return render(request, 'drax_internal_dbs/no_results.html')
```

This is my file:

```
<WSGIRequest: POST '/drax_output.html'> POST <MultiValueDict: {'file_query': [<InMemoryUploadedFile: calcitriol_2.xlsx (application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet)>]}>
```

When I try to read the file, I'm running into lots of issues. I'm using .read() to get the data and would like to convert it into a dataframe. The issues appear here, I don't know how to convert the data? I've been googling all day and still can't find a solution.
Here's what I've tried so far:

- Convert file into StringIO and use openpyxl.load_workbook
- Convert file into BytesIO and use openpyxl.load_workbook
- Use pandas.read_csv(file_contents=file.read())

And possibly other ways that I can't remember right now.
I don't want to save the file, as I will just use it to generate a table in HTML.

Thanks!

Comment: So what didn't work with what you tried so far?

Comment: When I converted to StringIO:
ValueError: negative seek value -45957336

Then I got other errors.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find an answer with xlsx. I instead moved onto using csv files as the input file, which worked pretty much instantly.